# Determine if Axios request is done

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

Is there any way to determine if a Axios request like the following received an answer and is done?

```
axios.get('/api')
.then(response => this.data = response.data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a promise and you can reference and `then` it:

```
var req = axios.get('/api')
               .then(response => this.data = response.data);
```

Now I want to react to it being done:

```
req.then(x => console.log("Done!"));
```

Or save that state outside:

```
var isReqDone = false;
req.then(x => isReqDone = true);
```